# Convert graph in to data points using Mechanical Turk?

Tags: graph, mechanicalturk

I looked around but did not see anyone using Mechanical Turk for this.  I've heard of the service, but never used it before.  I need to take the following graph and digitize it so I get a list of data points for each line (noting that there are two Y-axes, and thus depends on which line we are talking about).  This is pretty time consuming for me, and I saw other posts on StackOverflow about digitizing software doing a poor job at this.  Would Mechanical Turk be well suited to my task?

Here is the graph for reference:  http://www.yourpicturehost.com/dyno_hbspeed.jpg

Answer (score 1):

Depends how many of these you have. Mechanical turk could work quite well, but you'd have to check the accuracy carefully (eg by re-plotting the graphs, and comparing them yourself).

If you have a lot, though - you should be able to design an image processing algorithm to pick up the data.